# How to make inform 7 print a line of text after the serial number (line)?

Tags: inform7

I would like to print a line after the serial number line, like in the example below:

```
About About
A fancy story by A. Author
Release 1 / Serial number 190926 / Inform 7 build 6M62 (I6/v6.33 lib 6/12N) 
(Type “about” for credits and game information.)
```

Is this made with an extension? I didn't find anything about this in the documentation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
After printing the banner text:
    say "(Type 'about' for credits and game information.)"
```

Chapter 18.37 in the documentation.